# Read-in 1000 primes text file?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to complete an old laboratory worksheet in order to revise some java code as I have forgotten how to write (I am fairly new to coding). In one section of the code I have to read-in (as a ArrayList of Double) a text file that has been provided, containing the first 1000 prime numbers. So I currently have a basic method that needs to be adjusted in order to make it work effectively. I am also working with weights as part of a Fitness Function problem.

I then have to generate a number of random solutions to the Scales problem using (8) prime numbers.

So the code below, I need to edit in the appropriate places in order to read the file.

Thanks for your help :D!

```
static public ArrayList<Double> ReadNumberFile(String filename) {
    ArrayList<Double> res = new ArrayList<Double>();
    Reader r;
    try {
        r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        StreamTokenizer stok = new StreamTokenizer(r);
        stok.parseNumbers();
        stok.nextToken();
        while (stok.ttype != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            if (stok.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
                res.add(stok.nval);
            }
            stok.nextToken();
        }
    } catch (Exception E) {
        System.out.println("+++ReadFile: " + E.getMessage());
    }
    return (res);
}
```

Comment: What is the format of the file; that is, how are the numbers separated? Also, what is wrong with the code you posted? How does the current behavior compare to the expected?

Comment: And most important: what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The way you read the numbers will depend on the format of the file you are given, crucially, how the primes are delimited (i.e. what character separates one prime from the next). From here, I will assume that they are given to you with one prime on leach line.

```
File file = new File("primes.txt");  // get a file object referring to the list of primes
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());  // read all the lines, and store them in a List<String>
List<Double> primes = new ArrayList<>();  // initialize an empty list to put the primes

for (int i = 0; i < lines.length(); i++) {  // iterate over the lines
    primes.add(Double.parseDouble(lines.get(i)));  // convert each line into a double and add to the list
}
```

Some points:

- Prime numbers are all integers, you should use `int`s here.
- This can be made shorter (although less easy to explain to a beginner) by simply using:

```
List<Integer> primes = Files.lines(new File("primes.txt").getPath())
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .collect(Collectors.asList());
```

- This implementation is very fragile to the input format, and needs to be modified if they aren't given to you how I assumed. For example, if they are separated by commas, you will have to read them into a `String`, then use `string.split(",")` to get an array of values.